# How to fix Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null flutter firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, null

I am still trying to implement method to delete comment (if it is my own comment, or comment that was posted under my post), report user and/or block user (if I find their comments offensive or whatever). However, my method that calls dialog menu:

```
handleComments(BuildContext context) async {

DocumentSnapshot snap = await commentRef.doc(widget.post.postId)
    .collection('comments').doc(widget.comment.docId).get();
CommentModel comment = CommentModel.fromJson(snap.data());
bool isMe = widget.post.userId == comment.userId;
bool isComUser = currentUserId() == comment.userId;
if (isMe || isComUser)
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return SimpleDialog(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
        children: [
          SimpleDialogOption(
            onPressed: () {
              deleteComment(context);
            },
            child: Text(Languages
                .of(context)
                .deleteComment, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
          ),
        ],
      );
    });}
```

gives error:

```
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter (13165): Receiver: null
E/flutter (13165): Tried calling: []("docId")
E/flutter (13165): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core- 
patch/object_patch.dart:63:5)
E/flutter (13165): #1      new CommentModel.fromJson 
(package:blahblah/comments.dart:17:20)
E/flutter (13165): #2      _CommentsState.handleComments 
(package:blahblah/comment.dart:438:19)
E/flutter (13165): <asynchronous suspension>`
```

Even though adding comments to firestore is no problem, and CommentModel has all the fields in the doc (please, see pic)[image: firestore]

Where could be the issue? I went through several similar posts, but could not find the solution. Thank you for your help!

here is the CommentModel class:

```
class CommentModel {
String username, comment, userDp, userId, docId;
Timestamp timestamp;

CommentModel({
this.username,
this.comment,
this.timestamp,
this.userDp,
this.userId,
this.docId
});

CommentModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
username = json['username'];
comment = json['comment'];
timestamp = json['timestamp'];
userDp = json['userDp'];
userId = json['userId'];
docId = json['docId'];
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
data['username'] = this.username;
data['comment'] = this.comment;
data['timestamp'] = this.timestamp;
data['userDp'] = this.userDp;
data['userId'] = this.userId;
data['docId'] = this.docId;
return data;
}
```

}

Comment: you need to show your code for CommentModel.fromJson

Comment: apologies! I added the class clode

Answer (score 0):

From two [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66164586/) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67148437/), this issue originates from Firestore not being able to find the document you are requesting. I looked at your attached image and it shows multiple documents inside the `comments` subcollection. It appears that your second `doc()` call in your request is missing the required [documentID argument](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/doc.html):

```
DocumentSnapshot snap = await commentRef.doc(widget.post.postId).collection('comments').doc().get()
```

I tested a similar query in a test Flutter app and it also returned `null` in my case. The issue on my end was resolved after providing a documentID on all `doc()` method calls. If you would like to get all documents from the `comments` collection you can make use of this [documentation page](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#document--query-snapshots) for FlutterFire.

Comment: oh, thanks! That could be it! I also was thinking, that it was the id referencing issue... thanks anyways!

Comment: I edited the code, but still having the same NULL error. the edit was  DocumentReference doc_ref = await commentRef.doc(widget.post.postId).collection('comments').doc();
    DocumentSnapshot snap = await doc_ref.get();
    comment = new CommentModel.fromJson(snap.data()); Having trouble with this...

Comment: Have you tested using this statement for the DocumentReference? `DocumentReference doc_ref = await commentRef.doc(widget.post.postId).collection(‘comments’).doc(‘DOCUMENT_NAME_HERE’)`. You need to replace the DOCUMENT_NAME_HERE part with a document from the ‘comments’ subcollection, since your screenshot shows multiple documents inside this subcollection. Please see the full [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#one-time-read).

Comment: document_name_here is the automatically generated document id in the firestore sub-collection, is that right? so this must be dynamic. i cannot hard-set it as I do not know which comment user would want to take action on. would that be clear? so, this means I need to reference it correctly, and this is where I am struggling...

Comment: oh, after that code i also updated it... I understand that I need to fetch the docId, but how do I do it?

Comment: can someone help me pls! I am still stuck at this! thanks!

Comment: This is not an answer to this problem, did anyone else figure this out?